# logging in spring core application?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

How can I do logging using the `log4j.xml` in the spring core application? In Spring MVC I can configure it in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

How can I do this with spring core application? Can any one please give me a start up idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place same log4j.xml or log4j.properties file in the `src` folder so it will be placed at root after code is compiled and packaged.

And after that you can use it like that:

```
    public class MainApp {

           static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MainApp.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
          log.info("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need the log4j bridge since Spring uses commons-logging. [See here](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

Comment: I used `Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AspectClass.class);` . Is this correct way ?

Answer (score 0):

or you want to place some where else then you can give the path

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///C:/conf/log4j.xm.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It's depend upon your project suitability.